# How fps limiting works in pygame (specific example)

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate, deltatime

I recently wrote a program where I needed to limit the fps. After some searching I found a way via pygame built-in methods `pygame.time.Clock()` and `clock.tick(fps)` but an even better, more accurate way through the `time module`. But now comes the tricky part and that is `delta time` and its use in this example. As far as I know it is used to measure the time between frames to be able to calculate the movement of an object in real time. So my question is, how does `dt` help me limit fps and what is the meaning of the `sleep_time` variable in this example?

I will be grateful for any explanation and attempt to help with this topic

A quick note: *I'm also quite new to python and I'm still trying to understand it, but not programming in general and I already grasp the basics. What I don't understand is the algorithm behind the scenes. So that's basically all I need help with.* Thank you.

```
# Modules ---------------------------------------- #

import pygame as pg, time

# Initialization --------------------------------- #

pg.init()
pg.display.set_mode((720, 400))

# Variables -------------------------------------- #

prev_time = time.time()
FPS = 60
running = True

# Main-loop -------------------------------------- #
while running:
    current_time = time.time()
    dt = current_time - prev_time 
    prev_time = current_time
    sleep_time = 1./FPS - dt
    if sleep_time > 0:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the meaning of the sleep_time variable in this example?

The time required to process a single frame will be calculated for each frame. If it takes less than 1/60th of a second (i.e. sleep_time will be bigger than 0), put the process on hold for the remained of the 1/60th of a second, so that this frame actually takes 1/60th of a second.

`time.sleep(sleep_time)` suspends the thread for *at least* the duration of sleep_time (it [may be longer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)).

> how does dt help me limit fps

So in this example, the dt will be used to make sure you have a fixed/constant time step of `FPS`.

Sort of.

This way of limiting the framerate is not very good. I've modified the example in the question a bit with "printouts":

```
import time

prev_time = time.time()
FPS = 60
STEP_TIME = 1./FPS
running = True

count = 0
accum = 0

while running:
    current_time = time.time()
    dt = current_time - prev_time
    accum += dt
    count += 1
    if accum >= 1.0:
        accum -= 1.0
        print(count)
        count = 0
      
    prev_time = current_time
    sleep_time = STEP_TIME - dt
    if sleep_time > 0:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

With the results:

```
% py main.py
64
64
68
62
62
62
```

We don't get 60hz. For two reasons:

First, as mentioned, `time.sleep(sleep_time)` will guarantee that the thread sleeps for *at least* this amount of time. That is how the OS works. So you can't control precisely how long your program will be sleeping.

Second, let's take a closer look at `dt`.

```
dt = prev_time - current_time
```

so the `dt` is the time spent during *the previous* frame. That's fine and all, and it would likely work if we didn't want to throttle the framerate. The problem comes when we want to sleep. When we call `time.sleep(sleep_time)`, we're actually calling `time.sleep(1./FPS - (prev_time - current_time))`. We're actually fixing *last frames* time. This has a nasty effect of having some frames where we'll sleep, and other frames where we'll not sleep, resulting inconsistent frame times, at least from the user perspective; adding `print(dt, sleep_time)` at the end of the previous code snippet, we get something like:

```
% py main.py
0.0 0.016666666666666666
0.03285384178161621 -0.016187175114949545
0.0 0.016666666666666666
0.033695220947265625 -0.01702855428059896
0.0 0.016666666666666666
0.03452634811401367 -0.017859681447347005
0.0 0.016666666666666666
0.03141927719116211 -0.014752610524495443
0.0002942085266113281 0.01637245814005534
0.032390594482421875 -0.01572392781575521
0.0 0.016666666666666666
0.031510353088378906 -0.01484368642171224
0.0 0.016666666666666666
0.019999265670776367 -0.0033325990041097008
0.0005021095275878906 0.016164557139078776
0.03202223777770996 -0.015355571111043295
0.0006344318389892578 0.01603223482767741
0.03662467002868652 -0.019958003362019857
0.0 0.016666666666666666
```

To control the frame rate, I generally prefer the "busy loop" approach, which offers a more fine grained control w.r.t. using any sleep methods.

```
import time

prev_time = time.perf_counter()
current_time = prev_time
FPS = 60
STEP_TIME = 1./FPS
running = True

count = 0
accum = 0

while running:
    prev_time = current_time
    current_time = time.perf_counter()
    dt = current_time - prev_time

    accum += dt
    count += 1
    if accum >= 1.0:
        accum -= 1.0
        print(count)
        count = 0
    # print(dt)

    # busy loop, where we just wait this frame's time to pass
    while time.perf_counter() < (current_time + STEP_TIME):
        pass
```

Please note that instead of `time.time()`, I use `time.perf_counter()` which is much more precise for what we need to do.

With this method, I get this for the actual frame rate:

```
% py main.py
61
60
60
60
60
60
60
60
```

and this for individual frame time:

```
% py main.py
2.100015990436077e-06
0.016670000040903687
0.016669799922965467
0.016668600030243397
0.016668600030243397
0.016668800031766295
0.016668399912305176
0.01667120005004108
0.016669100034050643
0.016668599913828075
0.016668800031766295
0.016668800031766295
0.016668600030243397
0.016668399912305176
0.016669300035573542
0.0166680000256747
0.016668400028720498
0.016668399912305176
0.0166680000256747
```

Although `dt` is still about *last frame's* time, we're still controlling how *this frame's* time is spent.